# Is ms access database password protection useless?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I just created MS access database file and protected it with password. I am writing data from c# my app.

I just realized dropped mdb file into a tool shows instant password reveal. Wohila.

What is the alternative way to store data securely?

Comment: Access is not a database (in my world). Consider using a real database like Postgres, or at least SQLite if you need it portable and file-based.

Comment: Hi, Can I used SQLite with my C# program.

Comment: [MSDN:](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-12aa0e5c-34c6-4957-af3b-b5f5cfa9a766) : _In earlier versions of Access, you could create user accounts and passwords using a feature named user-level security. This topic does not discuss user-level security, which is not available when you use the .accdb file format.

If you encrypt a database and then lose the password, you will be unable to use the database. You cannot remove a database password if you do not know the password._

Comment: @TaW Is it safe to encrypt (.accdb) file with a password? Cant it be exploited? or bypassed the password?

Comment: @Alex If you refer to`MS Access`being a RAD tool,with an only use for simple tasks db (MDAC), I agree, but it contains a database!

Comment: @TaW you can't use the database, but you can extract the data, so it is not safe! For example [everythingaccess](https://www.everythingaccess.com/accessdatabaserepair_info.asp) can recover even protected code from accde.

Comment: @OP an [access db is not safe](https://www.everythingaccess.com/accessdatabaserepair_info.asp) unless App and MDAC are locked on a terminal server, so no one can access directly, only via remote app, but even then you have issues with e.g. backup or compacting or bitness (try to run different bitness of MDAC on a computer). Advice is to use sth. like`Ms Sql Server`,`MySQL`,`Postgres`,... as backend and Ms Access as frontend!

Comment: @learningprogramm Yes, you can easily do that. You can also use Entity Framework as ORM. Here's an example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1158937/SQLite-with-Csharp-Net-and-Entity-Framework